# Office 365 using the same Message-ID for warnings about IMAP Folder Name issues

Tags: exchange, microsoft-office-365

Does anyone know why Microsoft is using the same Message-ID values when sending System Messages for IMAP Folder Name issues?

I have noticed that customers using Office 365 are getting different messages from "Microsoft Outlook" that all use the exact same Message-ID value.  All the messages have different Sent dates and their Body content is different.  However, they all use the same SMTP Message-ID value.

This is causing issues with Duplicate Detection as many systems use the unique "Message-ID" to look for duplicates.

For example, the Message Subject is "One or more of the folders in your mailbox are named incorrectly." but all the various Message-ID values are exactly the same.  As I do not know if this Message-ID gives any customer information away, I will only give the first few characters and the other characters will be X.

The repeating Message-ID is: IMAP4{XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}

My guess is that Microsoft / Exchange might use this for easy reporting on their side, but this is a problem when trying to identify possible duplicate emails.

Thanks,
Geoff

Answer (score 0):

According to [RFC2822 - Internet Message Format](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2822.html),Message-ID (also known as Internet message ID or Client ID) is an identifier of emails, which refers to a particular version of a particular message.

This message identifier is intended to be machine readable and not necessarily meaningful to humans. Message ID should be unique for each instance of the message.

The uniqueness of the message identifier is guaranteed by the host which generates it. However, this identifier is not always unique. You can refer to the answer in [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/831183/is-the-message-id-email-header-unique-for-each-recipient)

Comment: Any progress with your question?

Comment: Hi Beverly,
Thank you for the information.  In what I am seeing each email is completely different.  They have different Bodies as they included the User that triggered the email.  It just seems that Microsoft is using the exact same Message-ID for every message they send out for that specific error.  I could understand if they were the same message, but they have different Send Dates and Bodies. 

I appreciate the searching and letting me know what you found.  

So far as I can tell, Office365 will always use the same Message-ID for any emails it sends to any customer about